# How would you encode a jwt using ColdFusion 9 or above syntax?

Tags: coldfusion, android-pay

[Their Python example](https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/docs/tutorial#1) seems to be the simplest, although I disagree with using the variable named cakeToken because that's confusing me with the Item Name being purchased:

```
cakeToken = jwt.encode(
  {
    "iss" : sellerIdentifier,
    "aud" : "Google",
    "typ" : "google/payments/inapp/item/v1",
    "exp" : int(time.time() + 3600),
    "iat" : int(time.time()),
    "request" :{
      "name" : "Piece of Cake",
      "description" : "Virtual chocolate cake to fill your virtual tummy",
      "price" : "10.50",
      "currencyCode" : "USD",
      "sellerData" : "user_id:1224245,offer_code:3098576987,affiliate:aksdfbovu9j"
    }
  },
  SELLER_SECRET)
```

Q: Where are they getting jwt from, or is that a variable that is being created?

I suppose SELLER_SECRET is a variable, populated from the [sandbox settings page](https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/customer/gadget/inapp/settings.html).

I think we would use dateadd('s',3600,now()) instead of time.time()+3600.

They also advise to use Google OpenID instead of rolling your own login, but that seems to be quite complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python example uses the [pyjwt library](https://github.com/progrium/pyjwt).  The Java version (which I imagine could be done easily in ColdFusion) uses the [jsontoken library](http://code.google.com/p/jsontoken/).  I don't see a jar download for the library, but it includes a Maven build file you could use to build one yourself.  All the libraries Google suggests are listed here: https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/docs/libraries